# AWK Error: Attempt to use array in a scalar context

Tags: awk

I am learning AWK. Here is a simple code snippet I tried to split a string into an array and iterate through it.

```
BEGIN {
  split("a,b,c", a, ",");

  for(i = 1; i <= length(a); i++) {
    print a[i];
  }
}
```

On running this code, I get the following error:

> awk: awk.txt:4: fatal: attempt to use array `a' in a scalar context

However, if I change the for statement to `for (i in a)` it works just fine. On further trying to understand what this means by Googling it, I see a number of forums (eg: [[1]](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.awk/gawk-length-array-question/192376)) talking about [awk bugs](http://awk.freeshell.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions#toc9). It will be great if AWK gurus here can help me understand what the error message means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`length` expects a string argument.  You are passing it an array.  The error message is telling you that you are using an array where a scalar is expected.

Answer (score 4):

```
BEGIN {
  count = split("a,b,c", a, ",");

  for(i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    print a[i];
  }
}
```

Also, `length(ARRAY)` works on my version of awk (GNU awk 4.0.1), but the documentation states that the behavior is non-standard.

Comment: I have GNU Awk 3.1.3 and I was expecting the length(ARRAY) to work. Just found this feature comparison chart for AWK: http://awk.freeshell.org/AwkFeatureComparison. From this, length(array) is supported starting GNU Awk 3.1.5