# array length fails in awk function body

Tags: awk

I don't have access to other `awk` versions to check the generality of this issue.

```
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.5
```

consider this simple test

```
$ awk 'function f(x) {x[1]} BEGIN{f(x); print length(x)}'
1
```

works as expected, however printing the length in the function body fails

```
$ awk 'function f(x) {x[1]; print length(x)} BEGIN{f(x)}'
awk: fatal: attempt to use array `x (from x)' in a scalar context
```

the only way to get the length of an array in a function body seems to be counting the elements `for(i in x) c++`

this is inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44528191/1435869)

Comment: I'm not familiar with awk at all, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12355329/1040092) could possibly shed some light

Comment: I'm on 4.1.1 and the latter prints 1.

Comment: Interesting that the bug only appears in the function context!

Comment: Under answer linked by @Wondercricket is [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355230/awk-error-attempt-to-use-array-in-a-scalar-context/12355329#comment16591220_12355393): _length(array) yes (new in 3.1.5), but not in POSIX mode_

Comment: Yes, good info.  However, it works in the main statement context.  Seems like function context has a different code path for the length calls.  That surprised me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once upon a time `length()` was for finding the number of characters in a string. Then gawk modified it to also find the number of elements in an array. Then POSIX adopted the gawk approach and here we are today with all awks cheerfully taking strings or arrays as arguments to length().

What you're experiencing doesn't happen in modern awk versions, it was a bug in gawk 3.1.5 and 3.1.6, see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-utils/2008-03/msg00028.html

Comment: yep, that explains.

Comment: _Once upon a time_ - there is no better way of starting it.