# Remove long prefix only from a specific field in all the lines of a file?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file containing the following lines (3 fields delimited by space):

```sh
component1 /dev/user/test 12344
component2 master abcefa123
component3 trunk 72812
component4 /branch/user/integration bc89fa
component5 trunk 989091 
component6 integration/test bc7829ac
component7 /branch/dev/user/various eded34512
```

I need to manipulate the field 2 to cut its long prefix (same as you do in bash with ${string##*}) and to get the following result:

```sh
component1 test 12344
component2 master abcefa123
component3 trunk 72812
component4 integration bc89fa
component5 trunk 989091 
component6 test bc7829ac
component7 various eded34512
```

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: With `awk`: use space and `/` as field separators and then output first, the second last field and last field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '{num=split($2,arr,"/");$2=arr[num]} 1' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** OR with shown samples only try setting field separators as space or `/`.

```
awk -F'[ /]' '{print $1,$(NF-1),$NF}' Input_file
```

***3rd solution(using `sed`):*** Using `sed`, you could try like:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\).*\/\(.*\)/\1 \2/' Input_file
```

***Explanation(1st solution):*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                   ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  num=split($2,arr,"/") ##Splitting 2nd field into array arr with / as field separator.
                        ##num is number of total elements of array arr.
  $2=arr[num]           ##Assigning last element of arr with index of num into 2nd field.
}
1                       ##Mentioning 1 will print the current line.
' Input_file            ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: 2nd and 3rd solution are not working. 2nd solution at component5 is wrong, 3rd solution is printing only component1,4,6,7

Comment: @cipid2001, I double checked all solutions and only 3rd was having issues, I have removed it now, with your shown samples all 3 mentioned in post now are working fine, kindly do let me know in case of any queries, 1st one should be more generic to your question, cheers.

Comment: 1st solution did the job.Thank you.

Comment: Very nice solutions, Ravinder! I only wonder why the second one suppresses `trunk` from the 5th line of the output. Does it also happen to you?

Comment: Oh, I see there is an extra trailing space in the 5th line in the sample file the asker provided. That causes NF=4 and thus `$NF` is empty. Deleting trailing spaces resolves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `AWK` for that following way, let content of `file.txt` be:

```
component1 /dev/user/test 12344
component2 master abcefa123
component3 trunk 72812
component4 /branch/user/integration bc89fa
component5 trunk 989091 
component6 integration/test bc7829ac
component7 /branch/dev/user/various eded34512
```

then

```
awk '{sub(/^.*\//, "", $2);print}' file.txt
```

outputs:

```
component1 test 12344
component2 master abcefa123
component3 trunk 72812
component4 integration bc89fa
component5 trunk 989091 
component6 test bc7829ac
component7 various eded34512
```

Explanation I simply replace everything from begin up to last `/` (which needs to be escaped hence `\`) in column of interest with empty string, then `print` it.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

A solution with awk:

`awk '{ split($2,s,"/"); $2=s[length(s)]; print }' inputfile`

The `split($2,s,"/")` will split the second varable to an array

`$2=s[length(s)];` will assign the second variable with the last value of the array

`print` will print the comlete line.

Comment: Because on some dispatchers where I'm testing, there are old awk versions, when using length function is throwing errors: "fatal: length: received array argument" - related to this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529958/array-length-fails-in-awk-function-body .  I've preferred the 1st solution in the post with split.

Comment: Yes, I agree,  the solution which get the length from the split statement is better. but if some site stil work wit 'older' versions, then it is time to upgrade.... 

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ split($2,map,"/");$2=map[length(map)] }1' file
```

Using awk. split the second space delimited field into an array called map using / as the delimiter. Substitute $2 with the last element of the map array. Print the lines with shorthand 1.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed -rn 's/(^.*)([[:space:]])(.*\/)?(.*)([[:space:]])(.*$)/\1 \4 \6/p' file
```

Split each line into sections based on regular expressions and substitute the line for the relevant sections, printing the result.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^([^ ]* )([^/]*\/)*/\1/' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

And also this `awk` using the loop `while`:

```
awk '{while ( n=split($2,a,/\//) ) {$2=a[n];print;next}}' file
component1 test 12344
component2 master abcefa123
component3 trunk 72812
component4 integration bc89fa
component5 trunk 989091
component6 test bc7829ac
component7 various eded34512
```